# Removing InMemoryWebApiModule for prod config on webpack for angular projects

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I'm using InMemoryWebApiModule to mock my data on dev but don't want it to be used for prod. Is there any technique to not use it for prod on webpack? atm I'm trying using webpack-strip-block to remove the import on webpack.prod config but can't get it working. anyone have any other idea on how to go about with it?

Answer (score 0):

there is this trick I had tried and it works in my case. Instead of dealing it from webpack, I changed the way we provide the respective providers to my main module,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DisplayNameComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: environment.production?[GetNameServiceService]:[GetNameServiceService, {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass: IBSInterceptor,multi: true}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

in my provider I check for the production environment first and then provide the providers array. I have implemented interceptor approach to complete the backend less development and when environment is production I dont inject full list of providers that I have otherwise for non prod environment.

I check environment.production (this will be true for production environment and will be false otherwise so accordingly I will have codes that I want to be shipped to production.

Comment: this is a good approach, but it would still import the module if I catch it this way? I was thinking more on the approach for when you compile with webpack before the app is actually run much like https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-strip-block does where it just removes anything in between the comments.